How to customize Argos GNOME shell extension
I have this Argos taskbar script / extension:

#!/usr/bin/env bash

# start bold
echo -n "\033[1m";
DATETIME=$(TZ='America/New_York' date +"%a %b %-d %H:%M %Z")
echo "$DATETIME (New York) | color=red";
# end bold
echo -n "\033[0m";

DATETIME=$(TZ='America/Costa_Rica' date +%H:%M\ %Z) ;
echo "$DATETIME (CR)";

DATETIME=$(TZ='America/Chicago' date +%H:%M\ %Z) ;
echo "$DATETIME (Texas)";

DATETIME=$(TZ='UTC' date +%H:%M\ %Z) ;
echo "$DATETIME";


How can I remove the bottom line, which points to my script?
How can I set certain text to show as #757575 color?

https://github.com/p-e-w/argos?tab=readme-ov-file#line-attributes says the "color" attribute is available, but it has never worked for me, even for basic colors like "red".
Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1528213/48214

First question
The Argos extension does not allow the filename to be hidden. Instead, you can follow these steps to hide the filename:

Edit the file button.js which is located in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/argos@pew.worldwidemann.com

Comment these which will be present at the bottom of the file:


/*
 *     if (dropdownLines.length > 0)
 *       this.menu.addMenuItem(new PopupMenu.PopupSeparatorMenuItem());
 * 
 *     let menuItem = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(this._file.get_basename(), {
 *       style_class: "argos-menu-item-edit"
 *     });
 *     menuItem.connect("activate", Lang.bind(this, function() {
 *       Gio.AppInfo.launch_default_for_uri("file://" + this._file.get_path(), null);
 *     }));
 *     this.menu.addMenuItem(menuItem);
 */

After saving the file, restart the GNOME using Alt+F2, entering "r" and press enter or logging out your current session.


Second question
You gave the color attribute in the wrong format for your second issue. Upon referring to README.md file on their repository, you might need to edit your script file as follows:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# start bold
echo -n "\033[1m";
DATETIME=$(TZ='America/New_York' date +"%a %b %-d %H:%M %Z")
echo " <span color='red'><tt>$DATETIME (New York)</tt></span>";
# end bold
echo -n "\033[0m";

DATETIME=$(TZ='America/Costa_Rica' date +%H:%M\ %Z) ;
echo "$DATETIME (CR)";

DATETIME=$(TZ='America/Chicago' date +%H:%M\ %Z) ;
echo "$DATETIME (Texas)";

DATETIME=$(TZ='UTC' date +%H:%M\ %Z) ;
echo "$DATETIME";


This will give you an output like this:


The first part worked. Thanks! +1 Unfortunately, colors still don't work for me even when using echo " <span color='red'><tt>$DATETIME (New York)</tt></span>"; like your example. Also, the https://github.com/p-e-w/argos/blob/master/README.md does mention the color approach I tried first too. Neither approach works for me yet.
